# What is dojo equivalent of jquery draggable

Tags: jquery, dojo, dojo-dnd

I am new to dojo, My jquery draggable function looks like as below,

```
$(function() {
    $( "#draggable" ).draggable();
  });
```

In dojo, Can we use dojo/dnd or dojox/floatingpane to achieve same results as above. In [this](http://jsfiddle.net/KGcTK/) example of dojo dnd, we deal with moving elements from one list to another but I don't find it is similar to jquery draggable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the closest equivalent is `dojo/dnd/Moveable`.  See http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/dnd/Moveable.html for documentation and an example.

Depending on what you ultimately want to do, you might also be interested in [`dijit/Dialog`](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dijit/Dialog.html).