# What is dojo equivalent of jquery droppable?

Tags: jquery, dojo, dojo-dnd

Jquery Droppable syntax is as below,

```
$('some_id').droppable(options);
```

Jquery draggable can be achieved with Dojo Movable - [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20014641/what-is-dojo-equivalent-of-jquery-draggable/20014782#20014782)

Any hints for droppable ?

Comment: Hi there! I think that dojo/dnd is what you search. Have a look here: http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/dnd.html#dojo-dnd We use this to make ContentPanes dragable and it worked great. Regards

Comment: Thanks @MiBrock, I think, dojo/dnd/Container should work, I will try this